# Powershell Win32_OperatingSystem select Caption compare with OS Version 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise' resulting wrong result

Tags: powershell

When I try to compare my OS version 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise' with Win32_OperatingSystem select caption result it is resulting false.

Example:

```
$Server='Computername' #Computername which has OS Version 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise'
$OSVersion = Invoke-command -computername $Server -scriptblock {Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem | select Caption}
#OS Version comparing with Win32_OperatingSystem caption
If ($OSVersion.Caption -eq 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise')
{
Write-Host 'True'
}
Else
{ Write-Host 'False'}
```

Result:

```
False
```

But it should result True. Could someone explain why it is resulting false even my OS Version and select caption is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this command

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName insert the computername | select Caption
```

Is the result really Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise ?

if i run you script like this on my computer

```
$Server='laptop090' #Computername which has OS Version 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise'
$OSVersion = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server | select Caption
#OS Version comparing with Win32_OperatingSystem caption
If ($OSVersion.Caption -eq 'Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview')
{
Write-Host 'True'
}
Else
{ Write-Host 'False'}
```

it work

Comment: For OS Version 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise' it is resulting false. Could you try on computer which is having OS Version 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise'

Comment: I don't have any server 2008 sorry but first make sure this commande get you the result you want before

Comment: Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName insert the computername | select Caption

Answer (score 0):

I executed below script to know why it is resulting 'False' for OS Version 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise'

```
$Server='ComputerName'
$OSVersion = 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise'
$OSVersionCaption = Invoke-command -computername $Server -scriptblock {Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem | select Caption}
$OSVersionCaption.Caption.length
$OSVersion.length

Result:
43
44
```

I really surprised by seeing the result. Length is not matching and found there was a space at the end of OS Version 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise ' caused this issue.
This issue is occured only for the OS Version 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise' and not for the other OS Version.

Conclusion there is no issue with the below command. Issue with the OS Version 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise'

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem | select Caption
```

Could someone try for OS version 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise' and confirm.